# Subjunctive Past: “We did not have to …”

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subjonctif

I would like to say something along the lines of “we did not have to + infinitive”.
Instead of present e.g. *il faut + infinitive*, I was thinking “il ne fallait pas”? But I struggled for it to make sense.
For example:

> We did not have to wear a uniform.

How would I say this?

Comment: note that even in the present, "il ne faut pas qu'on porte un uniforme" means "we must not wear a uniform" and not "it's not required that we wear a uniform."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If spoken French, the first person plural is fading out. You'll more likely hear:

- *On ne devait pas porter d'uniforme.* (Uniform forbidden) ("*ne devait*" is often pronounced "*n'devait*", the "*ne*" might even be dropped in lazy French - "*On devait pas...*")
- *On n'avait pas besoin de porter un uniforme.* (Uniform not needed)
- *On n'était pas obligés de porter un uniforme.* (Uniform not required)

Comment: Even though this is indeed fading out, I don't find the use of "nous" so strange to hear/read. I would also add "Nous n'étions pas obligés de..." , "Nous ne devions pas ..." . Also, in the case of a "forbidden uniform", I would rather use "Nous ne pouvions pas/On ne pouvait pas", because "ne devait pas" refers to an absence of obligation, while "ne pouvait pas" refers to an interdiction. Unless I've been wrong for a very long time :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. About *nous* vs *on* when used as the direct subject of a verb, the fact is the latter has mostly replaced the former in native spoken French and is only retained in formal speak nowadays. Studies about the subject show a usage trend slowing down to between 10% and less than 1%. See for example https://www.erudit.org/revue/arbo/2015/v/n5/1032665ar.pdf . About "Uniform forbidden", I agree with your remark. This part was not in my original reply and was added later by someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possibilities:

*Nous n'avons pas dû porter l'uniforme.*

*Nous n'étions pas obligés de porter l'uniforme.*

Comment: J'ajouterais "Nous n'avons pas eu à porter l'uniforme"